# How can a program on my CPU run the same way on another CPU?

Tags: cpu, instructions

Let's say that I would code a program with Windows API and then compile it. The code is compiled to machine code for the CPU to execute. Now, my question is: If I share the executable file for someone else with another instruction set in their CPU. How can their CPU run the code the same way and not give errors or run a different code?

Answer (score 1):

> someone else with another instruction set in their CPU
>   ...
>   How can their CPU run the code the same way

The code won't run. The CPU's, simply put, speak another language.

You have two options

1. recompile your code for the target CPU (assuming you can use the same source language and no platform specific API, so you're left with C/C++ with stdlib)
2. Write a script / bytecode and use a runtime available for both platforms to interpret the script (or bytecode)

That's why there are Runtime installations such as JVM (for Java) and scripts (Python, Scala, Lua, JavaScript, etc) where the code is in a form of a script or as platform independent code.

And now - next step. If you're using Windows API, well - as the name suggests - it's API (services) provided by the Windows system. So even using the same CPU without the Windows system (e.g. on a Linux system), the application won't run. (ok, there is often a way how to expose Windows API on Linux, but it can be tricky sometimes).

Conclusion: Binaries are not portable between instruction sets, if you're using any high level API (Win32, ...), you're pretty much hooked to the operating system too

Answer (score 0):

When high-level languages are compiled into executable, often they are compiled to intermediate code. This is a representation of the source code compiled closer to assembly language, however it is not specific to any CPU instruction set. It is up to the machine running the executable to interpret this intermediate code and run it in the CPU's native instruction set.